# Power Query - The field 'xxx' of the record wasn't found

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I want to add a new column to a source of data.

The new column's value is based on the data of the current row (`To Resolved date` and `From Activated date`) as well as data from another query (`Calendar`). Here is the a screenshot of the source data I am working on:

[image: Source data]

I am trying to get the number of rows of the other source (`Calendar`) that are within the range [`From Activated date`, `To Resolved date`]. For now, I have this formula for the new column (without the counting yet):

```
= Table.SelectRows(Calendar, each _[Date] >= [From activated date] and _[Date] <= [To Resolved date])
```

However, it does not work because Power Query does not find the columns `From Activated date` and `To Resolved date` in the `Calendar` query.

> Expression.Error: The field 'From activated date' of the record wasn't
>   found.
>
> Details:
>       Date=2017-01-01
>       Year=2017
>       MonthNumber=1
>       MonthName=January
>       Day=1
>       Weekday=1
>       WorkingDays=0

**Question**

How can I get the current values of `From Activated date` and `To Resolved date` for the current row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another query as a function - in this case, I named it 'CalendarRows':

```
(StartDate, EndDate) =>
let
    Source = Table.RowCount(Table.SelectRows(Calendar, each [Date] >= StartDate and [Date] <= EndDate))
in
    Source
```

Now add a column to your data table, referencing this function:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Calendar Rows", each CalendarRows([From activated date], [To Resolved date]))
```